# what does it mean "service in angular is stateless"

Tags: angularjs

Is service in AngularJS is stateless or singleton.

if it is stateless, then what conditions make it stateless.

Comment: Not only is your statement not a correct assessment, your code doesn't demonstrate anything.  All you have is a controller that does nothing, and a service that returns nothing, and isn't used by anything.  Essentially, this isn't an app at all.

Comment: When you don't know the answer or don't want to give an answer to the question, you just give it minus. If my question is not clear then clear it. You I am new and new students often do mistakes but it's the teacher who tries to understand the question and give the answer. Understanding question and giving answer is an art which you people don't have.

Comment: I think that I was very clear about what is wrong with your question.  You asked a question with an incorrect premise and tried to show code that does ***absolutely nothing at all***.  If you don't want to take the advice and try to clarify your question, that's fine, but don't blame others for the question's poor state.

Comment: I know my question is poor but you can answer that "why service in Angular is stateless". But you rather prefer to minus it. well, thanks for your advice and minus. I know the example given in the question does not fulfill the conditions but you can give me your example but you didn't. Thanks again buddy

Comment: You are missing the point.  Angular doesn't care if services are stateless or not.  You can make a service stateless, or you can make a service not stateless, and Angular won't complain.  Therefore, the real answer is, **the person who made that statement was misleading**.  The question is *absolutely not helpful to others* (the condition for the negative) because the question is completely flawed.

Comment: your edit makes things even less clear.  I can't say it any other way;  **Statelessness has nothing at all to do with Angular services**.  "my question is how and why this is stateless."  *how and why* ***what*** *is stateless?*.  Now you aren't showing anything at all.  If you are trying to figure out why someone else wrote a piece of code and made a claim that it was stateless, you should probably ask them, because we can't tell you what was in their head, and can't analyze a blank screen.

Comment: @WASIF Did you see an article making "Service in angular is stateless" comment somewhere?  If you link to the context of what you are referring to, then perhaps you'll get more elaboration on what the author / presentation is referring to.  HTTP is usually referred to as a stateless protocol.  If you read up more on what is meant by that perhaps that will help you understand the comment better.

Answer (score 2):

"service in Angular is stateless" - This is not a correct statement. Service in Angular is Singleton and there are five types of services - Provider, factory, service, value and constant.  You can find more details here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide

Comment: The fact that it is a singleton says nothing. A service can be either stateful or stateless.